# Error-0006 in SSOCircle while uploading SP metadata

Tags: single-sign-on, spring-saml, idp

This is my SP metadata

[image]

And same entityId mentioned in metadata, i added to FQDN field.After that while submitting it is showing 0006 error.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

After exporting metadata of my SP, I removed the preceding hyphens and I imported to IdP it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error. My issue was that I was leaving out `>` in my XML closing tag. Ensure you are copying your metadata properly